# Do I have to pay when deploy a project with one code account and one store data account

Tags: account, rent, account-data

I'm new to the Solana network.
I wonder do I need to pay rent for each account I deploy on Solana network. for example, if I have a project with one account store execute code and one project to store data which associate with account code. Did I need to deploy twice times and pay rent for both accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all accounts have to pay rent. Validators on the network need to maintain a copy of the state in memory; the cost of that is rent.

All accounts are required to be rent exempt by default. Executable or non-executable accounts.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent